# Artifactory test connection from jenkins gets failed with timed out

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I'm using Jenkins Artifactory Plugin and I have this error:

```
Error occured while requesting version information: 

connect to [myurl..:8081] failed: connection timed out: connect
```

I can login to the Artifactory UI but the connection from Jenkins (using Jenkins Artifactory plugin) is failed.

is it something MYSQL database error!?

Comment: jenkins and artifactory both are in different machine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks that you don't have connection between machines.

Can you check it? Launch a ping from your Jenkins machine to your Artifactory machine.

From Jenkins machine:

```
ping ArtifactoryMachine
```

Comment: You don't connection between machines, it's the reasen because the message ping: unknown host http:// <URL> and the reason of your Jenkins time out. Yo need to enable the connection between your machines.

Comment: how can i enable it?! if i do ssh to artifactory machine from jenkin machine. i am able to login

Comment: @PiyushbhaiSadseliya You have connection with SSH but not with HTTPS. Jenkins Artifactory plugins don't work with SSH. You have 2 options, to enable HTTPS connection between your machines or to enable SSH in Jenkins an build a custom pipeline to deploy to Artifactory.

Comment: that makes sense. could you please share any reference document to configure this?that would be really helpful

Comment: @PiyushbhaiSadseliya I recommend you these posts: [How to publish artifacts via SSH in Jenkins](https://medium.com/@weblab_tech/how-to-publish-artifacts-in-jenkins-f021b17fde71) and [SSH integration in Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/SSH+Integration)

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling the firewall with ufw disable if it's a Linux machine.